# Android Studio display this error : ClassNotFoundException com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Sq;ServerDriver

Tags: sql-server, gradle

I want to insert record to MSSQL directly (not using Api or Webservice..)

I try to insert, but receive this error :

```
ClassNotFoundException com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Sq;ServerDriver
```

I think I should add this driver to Gradle, but I don't know how to add it.

Please help me